# Is a Sony Vaio Z Power Media Dock with AMD Radeon HD 6650M graphics a recommend buy?

Tags: laptop, ati, vaio, sony

Has anyone tried the Sony Vaio Z Power Media Dock with AMD Radeon HD 6650M graphics under Linux? Does it work with Bumblebee hybrid graphics? I am considering it as a potential update of my current laptop.

Answer (score 2):

don't!!! it can't handle the switchable graphics card no matter what i try. i have seen a bunch of claims of people getting it to work in Linux but when i do what they say works it just gets errors. save your self the headache and get a non switchable gpu.